# How does event handler "event" parameter work?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dom-events

I just wrote a piece of code in Javascript where I added an event Listener and then I wrote the event Handler like this:

```
function checkBoxes() {
   const answer=event.currentTarget;
   ...
   ...
}
```

I always thought that it was mandatory to write a parameter in order to use the Event object in a handler, but this code still works, and I would like to know why.

Comment: Browsers keep a global `event` value, originally a very bad idea implemented by Internet Explorer back a very long time ago, but now common for compatibility reasons.

Comment: So it's only a good practice to write "event" as a parameter?

Comment: That would be my recommendation, but it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Pointy I don't think anyone would disagree with that opinion

Answer (score 1):

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event):

> The read-only Window property event returns the Event which is currently being handled by the site's code. Outside the context of an event handler, the value is always undefined.